# Query Objects list on Django API RESTframework But results only one object

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, postman

Hello API RESTframework Expertise

I have tables as below

- user
- employee_profile (emprofile)
- employee_list (emplist)
- Organization (org)

I have user-fk with employee-profile (emprofile) table, emprofile-fk with employee-list (enlist), emplist-fk with Org

And I have:

- 3 users in user table
- 3 employees in emprofile table
- User 1 have created a organization and user 2 also created another organization
  User 3 also created own organization too
  User 1 invite user 2 to join on emplist of organization owned by user 1.
- 3 Organizations in org table

I want to get results to display 2 Organizations when user2 is logged in.

I am trying to code as images function print has 2 objects correctly but in API (Postman) query show up only 1.

How can I get 2 objects as print results.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cx1ce.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQyQ9.jpg)

Comment: please paste your code in image as well to reproduce

Comment: Please  post code not screenshot.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an empty list at the start of your def (not in for loop)

```
result=[]
```

And push your serializer.data there in for loop:

```
result.append(serializer.data)
```

And then return the result value

Comment: class Orglist(APIView):
def get(self, request):
list= []
user = self.request.user
emprofile=EmployeeProfile.objects.filter(user=user).first()
empList = EmployeeList.objects.filter (employee profile=emprofile)
for i in empList:
id = int(i.org.id)
org = Organiaztion.objects.filter(id=-id)
serializer = OrganiaztionSerilaizers(org, many=True)
list.append (serializer.data)
print (list.append (serializer.data))
return Response(list.append (serializer.data))

Comment: Not working it's response "none"

Comment: If you can give me example code for this purpose is much more appropriate, thanks